# Environment Variables when running from cron Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a few Scrapy Python scripts which use AWS CloudWatch for logging using the watchtower module. This is in a docker container. Everything works absolutely fine when run manually. I am now looking to get cron jobs to schedule each scraper. This is when it breaks. As it is in a docker container, I cannot find out where the cron logs are kept.

The entry point to the docker container is:

```
CMD cron -L15 && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

However, the file /var/log/cron.log is empty.

The cron.d/spiders file is very basic at the minute as I test:

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/scrapy runspider /spiders/myspider.py
```

If I remove the logging using CloudWatch and watchtower the scraper runs as expected.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchtower

If I run the command from within the docker container

```
/usr/local/bin/scrapy runspider /spiders/myspider.py
```

from within the docker container with the logging back in the file it works as well. I believe the issue is with the environment variables. Watchtower looks in the environment variables for

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=

So the issue is when run by cron, the environmental variables are not available. I tried running

```
env >> /etc/environment
```

but this didn't work.